# Getting invalid output

Tags: java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = {1,3,7,9,2};
    System.out.println( twoSum(arr,11));
   

}
public static int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        Integer requiredNum = (target - numbers[i]);
        if(indexMap.containsKey(requiredNum)){
            int toReturn[] = {indexMap.get(requiredNum), i};
            return toReturn;
        }

        indexMap.put(numbers[i], i);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

When i run this i get invalid output like [I@d041cf this but i except on 2 output as array why this is happening?

Comment: You seem to be missing `Arrays.toString`

Comment: ya now it fine But why it need Array.toString for this those two where of int array when why string ?

Comment: When you print an array directly, you print a reference to a memory address, rather than the content of it